# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'

Tags: qgis

I'm using QGIS and I've install the plugin "Giswater" with success, but when I try to reload the software it's open an error message. I've try all the versions of Giswater but the error still happen.
How can I solve it?

```
MacOS
QGIS 3.22.16
Giswater 3.4

Impossibile caricare il plugin 'giswater' a causa di un errore chiamando il metodo classFactory() 

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL' 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py", line 423, in _startPlugin
    plugins[packageName] = package.classFactory(iface)
  File "/Users/pippi/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/giswater/__init__.py", line 32, in classFactory
    from .giswater import Giswater
  File "/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py", line 888, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "/Users/pippi/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/giswater/giswater.py", line 43, in 
    from .map_tools.draw_profiles import DrawProfiles
  File "/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py", line 888, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "/Users/pippi/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/giswater/map_tools/draw_profiles.py", line 16, in 
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  File "/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py", line 888, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib-3.3.0-py3.8-macosx-10.13.0-x86_64.egg/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 36, in 
    import matplotlib.colorbar
  File "/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py", line 888, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib-3.3.0-py3.8-macosx-10.13.0-x86_64.egg/matplotlib/colorbar.py", line 44, in 
    import matplotlib.contour as contour
  File "/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py", line 888, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib-3.3.0-py3.8-macosx-10.13.0-x86_64.egg/matplotlib/contour.py", line 17, in 
    import matplotlib.text as text
  File "/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py", line 888, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib-3.3.0-py3.8-macosx-10.13.0-x86_64.egg/matplotlib/text.py", line 16, in 
    from .textpath import TextPath  # Unused, but imported by others.
  File "/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py", line 888, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib-3.3.0-py3.8-macosx-10.13.0-x86_64.egg/matplotlib/textpath.py", line 11, in 
    from matplotlib.mathtext import MathTextParser
  File "/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py", line 888, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib-3.3.0-py3.8-macosx-10.13.0-x86_64.egg/matplotlib/mathtext.py", line 27, in 
    from PIL import Image
  File "/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py", line 888, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'


Versione Python: 3.8.7 (default, Feb 10 2021, 09:04:08) [Clang 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.29)] 
Versione di QGIS: 3.22.16-Białowieża Białowieża, 6f08e4d7b0 

Percorso Python:
/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python
/Users/pippi/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python
/Users/pippi/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins
/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/plugins
/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/python3.8
/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/python3.8/site-packages/opencv_contrib_python-4.3.0.36-py3.8-macosx-10.13.0-x86_64.egg
/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/python3.8/site-packages/patsy-0.5.1-py3.8.egg
/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyproj-2.6.0-py3.8-macosx-10.13.0-x86_64.egg
/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cftime-1.2.1-py3.8-macosx-10.13.0-x86_64.egg
/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/python38.zip
/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/python3.8/site-packages/statsmodels-0.11.1-py3.8-macosx-10.13.0-x86_64.egg
/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/python3.8/site-packages
/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/python3.8/site-packages/netCDF4-1.5.4-py3.8-macosx-10.13.0-x86_64.egg
/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/python3.8/site-packages/geopandas-0.8.1-py3.8.egg
/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rasterio-1.1.5-py3.8-macosx-10.13.0-x86_64.egg
/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/python3.8/site-packages/snuggs-1.4.7-py3.8.egg
/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numba-0.50.1-py3.8-macosx-10.13.0-x86_64.egg
/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click_plugins-1.1.1-py3.8.egg
/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/python3.8/site-packages/Fiona-1.8.13.post1-py3.8-macosx-10.13.0-x86_64.egg
/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib-3.3.0-py3.8-macosx-10.13.0-x86_64.egg
/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/python3.8/site-packages/Rtree-0.9.4-py3.8.egg
/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy-1.20.1-py3.8-macosx-10.13.0-x86_64.egg
/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/python3.8/site-packages/GDAL-3.2.1-py3.8-macosx-10.13.0-x86_64.egg
/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/python3.8/site-packages/affine-2.3.0-py3.8.egg
/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas-1.1.0-py3.8-macosx-10.13.0-x86_64.egg
/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload
/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy-1.5.1-py3.8-macosx-10.13.0-x86_64.egg
/Users/pippi/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python
/Users/pippi/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/giswater/ui/..
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Python Image Library](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) (PIL) is a third-party Python library to add imagery manipulation functionality to your code.
Oddly I see that PIL is natively installed with QGIS so the problem is unlikely due to the plugin itself.  On my Windows computer that installation location is here:  C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.22.4\apps\Python39\Lib\site-packages\PIL.

Best to migrate this question to the [creator's forum page](https://www.giswater.org/foro/) or a [different Stack Exchange](https://apple.stackexchange.com/) site for more focused help if you find you do not have PIL installed with your QGIS Python installation or if you want to install PIL yourself to your Python Libray folder on Mac OS.